# How to make Thunderbird's UI less cluttered (look more like Apple Mail)?

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird

I'm switching from OS X to Linux and one of the most challenging aspects has been transitioning from Mail's lean, clean interface, to Thunderbird's Account/Folder smorgasbord. For example, this is my folder view in Mail, with 4 IMAP accounts and 2 Smart/Dynamic folders:

[image: Mail's slick interface]

If you click the triangle next to Inbox, you can see the inbox of each account, but for the most part, the top-level, aggregated inbox is perfect.

I looked for add-ons, but couldn't find anything. Alternatively, is there a another Linux client that does this?

Comment: You may want to look into "trenta os" its a linux distro with the look and feel of mac OS X.

Comment: I did, but had some problems with the default Mail client and other apps. However, seems I was lazy, and assumed the Mail client was outdated, when it actually works fine. So, I might give that another shot. Do you want to type up an answer referring to Geary (the Mail client forked in Elementary?). I would pick that as the answer.

Comment: What exactly would you like to change? As far as the folder sidebar is concernd, TB doesn't look much different from your Apple mail screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried simply minimizing things you don't want to see in TB?  You can make it look pretty much like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into "Trenta OS" a linux distro based on Ubunto that gives the use and feel of Mac OSX.

It has Geary, a mail client forked in Elementary, which should work the way you want.